# Posting object to Google Cloud Storage doesn't replace ${filename} variable

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

As described here https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object

I can use `${filename}` as part of the key when uploading a file to GCS from the browser (using a signed request).

That's great, because it's the exact same variable S3 uses. But - a problem. It doesn't actually replace `${filename}` with the name of the file when I upload. This works perfectly on S3, but with GCS I literally get `$%7Bfilename%7D` as the key in the response - clearly it's not replacing this with the correct value.

I'm building the request like so:

```
export function uploadVideo(video) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!video) {
      resolve(null);
      return;
    }
    // this fetches a presigned post object from the server:
    request.get('/presigned_post')
      .query({format: 'json'})
      .end((err, response)=> {
        if (!err && response.ok) {
          request
            .post(`https://${response.body.url.host}/`)
            .field(response.body.fields)
            .field('Content-Type', image.type)
            .attach('file', image, image.name)
            .end((err, response) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log("Error uploading image: ", err);
                reject(err);
              } else {
                resolve({
                  location: response.text.match('<Location>' + '(.*?)' + '</Location>')[1],
                  bucket: response.text.match('<Bucket>' + '(.*?)' + '</Bucket>')[1],
                  key: response.text.match('<Key>' + '(.*?)' + '</Key>')[1],
                  checksum: response.text.match('<ETag>"' + '(.*?)' + '"</ETag>')[1]
                });
              }
            });
        }
      });
  });
}
```

The key is `some_folder/${filename}` and this is included in the form data to google (in `response.fields`).

You can see I **am** providing the filename with `.attach('file', image, image.name)`. It **is** uploading correctly, just not replacing the `${filename}` var.

*edit*

I have narrowed down the issue more. We query S3 and GCS to get the fields in the presigned post. With S3, if I give a key of `${filename}` then I get exactly that returned in the fields:

```
  def presigned_post(bucket_name:, key:, **opts)
    response = s3_resource.
      bucket(bucket_name).
      presigned_post(key: key, content_type_starts_with: '', **opts)

    {
      fields: response.fields,
      url:    { host: URI.parse(response.url).host }
    }
  end
```

Fields here will contain `"key"=>"${filename}"`.

However in the GCS case, the following code returns `:key=>"$%7Bfilename%7D"` in the fields:

```
# https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#usage_and_examples
# https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/google-cloud-storage/1.0.1/Google/Cloud/Storage/Bucket:post_object
def presigned_post(bucket_name:, key:, acl:, success_action_status:, expiration: nil)
  expiration ||= (Time.now + 1.hour).iso8601

  policy = {
    expiration: expiration,
    conditions: [
      ["starts-with", "$key", "" ],
      ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "" ],
      { acl: acl },
      { success_action_status: success_action_status }
    ]
  }

  post_obj = get_bucket!(bucket_name).post_object(key, policy: policy)

  url_obj = { host: URI.parse(post_obj.url).host }

  # Have to manually merge in these fields
  fields = post_obj.fields.merge(
    acl: acl,
    success_action_status: success_action_status
  )

  return { fields: fields, url: url_obj }
end
```

If i manually change the key in the GCS request fields, then it works. Is that really what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: I understand that your issue is here `request.post(`https://${response.body.url.host}/`)`. You could try escaping the characters that are giving you problems ( { } ) with a backslash ( \ )

Comment: @Miguel no, that part is just JS string interpolation (note the string has backticks). The issue is one of the form fields: `key='${filename}' (not js interpolation). I will try escaping it though

Comment: @Miguel see update to the question

Comment: Could you please specify where the `${filename]` var is specified? I cannot find it in the code you shared

Comment: Hey @Miguel. You are right that it's not present in the code I shared. I'm passing it as the `key` arg when calling `presigned_post`. I figured out this issue is caused by the `google-cloud-storage` ruby gem, specifically `google-cloud-storage-0.24.0/lib/google/cloud/storage/file.rb` in `def ext_url`, which is called from `def post_object`. I'm going to raise an issue on their Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix for this issue was released in [google-cloud-storage v1.24.0](https://rubygems.org/gems/google-cloud-storage/versions/1.24.0).

Comment: Link to quartzmo's PR if anyone's interested: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/commit/13d26a0ce6c8c5516d068e6f6b1382612670b706

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue is caused by:

```
      def ext_path
        URI.escape "/#{@bucket}/#{@path}"
      end
```

in `lib/google/cloud/storage/file.rb` of the google-cloud-ruby-gem.

This is called by `def post_object` in that same file.

I am going to raise an [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/issues/4047) on their Github page.

Comment: Could you link the GitHub issue in your answer? Doing so will help future users experiencing this same issue.

Comment: @Miguel yes linked it